# Why flatlist is not sorted after sorting the array?

Tags: javascript, react-native, sorting

I'm creating a flatlist that outputs array of object from an API. Before outputting the array, It will be sorted alphabetically and another data will be added at the top of the array. The problem is that the data is not sorted when rendered in the flatlist and the new data that was added is missing.

```
const defaultListTab = {id: 18, name: "All"};
const [listTab, setListTab] = React.useState([]);

.then(function (result) { 
    setListTab(result.data.categoriesData)
    listTab.sort(function (a, b){
        if(a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase()) {
            return -1;
        } else if(a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
    setListTab(listTab => [defaultListTab, ...listTab])
)};
return () => abortCont.abort();
```

This is what the array looks like originally:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "id": 29,
    "name": "Fruit",
  },
  Object {
    "id": 30,
    "name": "Vegetable",
  },
  Object {
    "id": 31,
    "name": "Dessert",
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first call to `setListTab` you're setting the state to `result.data.categoriesData`.

Then you're trying to sort `listTab`, but in this moment, the state still empty `[]`, because react have not rendered it yet.

Sort the results of your request before, than later set the state.

Something like this:

```
result.data.categoriesData.sort()...

setListTab([defaultListTab, ...result.data.categoriesData]);
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that `listTab` is not updated instantly because `setListTab` is an async operation

change your code like this

```
const defaultListTab = {id: 18, name: "All"};
const [listTab, setListTab] = React.useState([]);

.then(function (result) { 
    setListTab(result.data.categoriesData)
    
    setListTab(listTab => {
      listTab.sort(function (a, b){
        if(a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase()) {
            return -1;
        } else if(a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
    return [defaultListTab, ...listTab]

    })
```

when you use a callback inside you setState function it will get the updated value

Comment: i tried your method but the flatlist doesnt show any of the data. After the then(), I implement a `return () => abortCont.abort();`. Having the return inside then() would ignore the abort(), right?